# Return new line by grep if not match found

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I would like to modify this code to return an empty line if no match is found by grep:

```
while read vl ; do grep "^$vl" Table_S4.tab ; done < 1
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
while read vl; do
    grep "^$vl" Table_S4.tab || printf "\n"
done < 1
```

If `grep` doesn't find a match, the `printf` command will be run and output an empty line.

Comment: whats the  '< 1' at the end?

Comment: I assume the OP created a file with the name `1`, and @chepner kept the structure the same to be consistent. The contents of the file named `1` will be read in line-by-line due to the `while read vl`, and each line will be processed by `grep`.